# Widgetkit Drupal alternative

Tags: 7, entities, media

Is there module that will enable user to create galleries and than embed them into article content, and display them in lightbox fashion?

For example, I can create a gallery in some UI, configure it (set gallery type, transition effects etc...) and than get gallery ID which I can use to embed it in article with some shortcode:

```
Some text...
[image_gallery ID1]
Rest of the text
[image_gallery ID2]
...
...
```

I have searched through drupal repositories and on google and didn't find anything like it. So I'd like to know if someone knows better or do I have to implement that functionality from scratch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the [**Photowall**](https://drupal.org/project/photowall) project to see if it matches your requirements out of the box.

From the project page:

> Provides a Photowall (like Google) format for displaying images, using the [JQuery Photowall](http://creotiv.github.com/jquery-photowall/) plugin.

There is a nice demo showing what it does at the  [JQuery Photowall](http://creotiv.github.com/jquery-photowall/) link.

If it is not advanced enough for your tastes, I have another idea:

Since most of the power of the [YooTheme Widgetkit](http://www.yootheme.com/widgetkit) for Joomla and Wordpress is provided by Javascript that runs in the browser and that should work just as well when it is launched from Drupal instead of Joomla/Wordpress, it should not be too hard to adapt the Drupal module **Photowall** to make use of the *YooTheme Widgetkit* Javascript plugin, instead of the *JQuery Photowall* Javascript plugin (but it will obviously require some custom development).

Comment: Yes, I actually think I'll make my own plugin/module after all, this is indeed the closest thing to what I was looking for but not quite. Thanks.